# How to assign values to avoid duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe

| date | variable | tag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | A1 | xy1 | 3 |
| 1/1 | A1 | xy2 | 2 |
| 2/1 | B2 | xy1 | 4 |
| 2/1 | B2 | yy2 | 4 |
| 2/1 | C3 | xy1 | 4 |
| 2/1 | C3 | yy2 | 4 |

I want to select tag for each variable for each date based on Highest count. Now for **A1** it's easy, it will be **xy1** as it has the highest count(3). Now for **B2** and **C3** it's a bit tricky as both tags has same count for both variables. But what we know is one tag uniquely belong to either B2 or C3. So we could Assign any tag to B2 and the other one will go to C3. What we don't want is to assign same tag to both B2 and C3. Variable and tags are not a unique combination but there combination is unique for a given date.

Final dataframe could look either of the following
**Option 1**

| date | variable | tag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | A1 | xy1 | 3 |
| 2/1 | B2 | yy2 | 4 |
| 2/1 | C3 | xy1 | 4 |

**Option 2**

| date | variable | tag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | A1 | xy1 | 3 |
| 2/1 | B2 | xy1 | 4 |
| 2/1 | C3 | yy2 | 4 |

How could we achieve this with pandas or python in general?

Comment: What if there are more variables than tags, so there's no possible assignment without duplicates?

Comment: Anyway, a way to do it is to put all the unique tags for the count in a list. Then loop through the variables and tags in parallel, assigning the tags to the `tag` column of the result.

Comment: Well, number of variable will always be greater or equal to number of tags and if they are equal tags will be unique for each variable. If you can elaborate your ans @Barmar then that would be helpful. I am using pandas for the analysis

Comment: Sorry, I don't know pandas well enough to elaborate. I hoped that this suggestion would point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can the same variable be allocated at different dates ? For instance yy2 would be chosen for C3 at 2/1, and D4 at 3/1 ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to consider the problem with regards to tags instead of date variable. Indeed, we aim to maximize the count on the tag for a specific date/variable couple. If we sort the array along the count (decreasing order) and take tags, we will end up with an allocation strategy. Taking the biggest tag, we will take couple in order and remove:

- the chosen variable (the variable is already associated with a tag on this date)
- chosen tag (the tag is already allocated to a variable on that date).

We look in the remaining dataset for the rest of the allocation.

Here is an implementation

```py
from collections import defaultdict as ddict
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["1/1", "1/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1"],
        "variable": ["A1", "A1", "B2", "B2", "C3", "C3"],
        "tag": ["xy1", "xy2", "xy1", "yy2", "xy1", "yy2"],
        "count": [3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    }
)
df.sort_values("count", ascending=False, inplace=True)

assignments = ddict(list)

for tag in set(df["tag"]):
    var_df = df[df["tag"] == tag]

    for (date, variable), grouped_df in var_df.groupby(
        ["date", "variable"], sort=False
    ):
        if (
            (df["date"] == date) & (df["variable"] == variable) & (df["tag"] == tag)
        ).any():
            assignments[tag].append([date, variable, tag, grouped_df["count"].iloc[0]])
            same_variable_date_df = df[
                (df["date"] == date)
                & ((df["tag"] == tag) | (df["variable"] == variable))
            ]
            df.drop(
                list(same_variable_date_df.index),
                inplace=True,
            )


assigned_df = pd.DataFrame(
    sum(assignments.values(), []), columns=["date", "variable", "tag", "count"]
)
print(assigned_df)
```

It returns

```
  date variable  tag  count
0  2/1       B2  xy1      4
1  1/1       A1  xy1      3
2  2/1       C3  yy2      4
```